# Video player with command line that can start playing and looping on a selected period

Tags: command-line, video

I'm looking for command line tool  that can start playing and looping a video clip on a selected section of that video.

If you know such tool, please share.

**For user `devnull`**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/).  For example,

```
vlc /path/to/video --loop --start-time 100 --stop-time 150
```

would start the video at 100 seconds and stop it at 150 seconds.  `--loop` would cause it to play the video indefinitely.

In order to display the full help for `vlc`, you can use the `-H` option:

```
vlc -H
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of your `/path/to/video` ? I try to put in `file:///C:\Path\To\File` does not work for me.

Comment: I upload the error in my question

Comment: @NamG.VU [This](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=111972) might help.

Comment: My folder Security's properties is full to my Windows account. So the link not works for me @devnull